# how can I make a union without actually using union in c?

Tags: c, unions

I need to create a union in c without using the `union` keyword.

```
x = 1;

…

x = ‘c’;

…

x = 3.1415; /* the data type of x changes during runtime. */

…
```

I am trying to not use array either.

Comment: Is this of pure academic curiosity, or do you have a real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Why??? If you need a union, use a union.

Comment: I think you need to read about [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and then clarify your question.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, you cannot make a `union` without declaring a `union`, because a `union` is a convenience syntax for sharing storage in a standard-compliant way. There is no such thing as "union command", though.

If all you want is an ability to store values of different types in a shared memory space, pick a type of maximal size among the types that you wish your pretend-union to cover, and make assignments using pointer casts:

```
long long shared;
*((int*)&shared) = 5;
*((char*)&shared) = 'c';
*((float*)&shared) = 3.14f;
```

Comment: this works as requested but for sure is not really what he wants. He really wants c to be python or javascript - which it isnt. (BTW - comment on question, not yr excellent reply)

Comment: note to OP : this code is what union would have done for you but in a clear well understood way

Comment: Also worth noting that this code assumes `long long` satisfies the size and alignment requirements of all the types you’re going to be using it as. When in doubt, `assert(sizeof(long long) >= sizeof(int) && alignof(long long) >= alignof(int) && ...)`

Comment: Wouldn't that break strict aliasing?